# Check if user input matches ID of any node in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am at a point of my assignment where the system displays a list of items from the linked list.

Then the user needs to input a ID of a product they wish to purchase, and then I "THINK" I must scan through linked list to find the node with that ID, then display some data from the node to the screen.

I was wondering how this would be achieved?

Please note:
I have struct Node.
I have Struct List.
I have struct Stock.

system holds List * itemList

Node points to List, List points to Stock (where data is held, id...etc)

Would it be something like this?

```
void purchaseItem(VmSystem * system)
{
system.itemList * list;
Node * node = list->head;
char userInput[ID_LEN+NULL_SPACE];

printf("please select id: ");
fgets(userInput, userInput.len, stdin);

while(head.data.id != userInput && node != NULL)
{
node = node->next;
}

if(head.data.id == userInput)
{
/*print required data*/
{
else
{
/*error*/
}

}
```

Comment: It's best to show a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: Presumably your `node` would have a `data` and an `id` field that you could compare with....

Comment: Perhaps showing the definitions of your structs would enable us to help you in a better way.

Comment: Oh sorry guys. I figured it out :D Sorry to inconvenience you though. BUT i do have another problem now, which my brain is just too worked to figure out i think. I am going to post it up now. Thanks again